# Python unclear regex behavior

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem with python regex. The result seems fine on regxe buddy, but fails in python.

Set of data i have to match is a list:

```
['  101  0.  0.\n',
 '  0.  100.\n',
 '  1.  98.5107805\n',
 '  2.  97.0464459\n',
 '  3.  95.6065328\n', ... ]
```

I have to get all the numbers starting from second line. 
For this i used:

```
pattern = compile(r'\s*(?P<raw_time>\d*\.?\d*)\s+(?P<raw_value>\d*\.\d*)')
```

And all worked fine. I iterate through the list and get the first value in "raw_time" and second one in "raw_value" for every line. 
Then i was supposed to expand the term to also work with weighted data.

So the data turned to:

```
['  101  0.  0.\n',
 '  0.  100.  1\n',
 '  1.  98.5107805  1\n',
 '  2.  97.0464459  1\n',
 '  3.  95.6065328  1\n', ... ]
```

I still just have to parse out two first parameters. So i changed the pattern to:

```
pattern = compile(r'\s*(?P<raw_time>\d*\.?\d*)\s+(?P<raw_value>\d*\.\d*).+')
```

It works fine all lines except the 1.

Working:

```
In [35]: pattern.search('1.  98.5107805  1\n').groupdict()
Out[35]: {'raw_time': '1.', 'raw_value': '98.5107805'}
```

Working:

```
In [37]: pattern.search('  0.  100.  1\n').groupdict()
Out[37]: {'raw_time': '0.', 'raw_value': '100.'}
```

Working:

In [44]: pattern.search('1.  98.5107805\n').groupdict()
   Out[44]: {'raw_time': '1.', 'raw_value': '98.510780'}

Not working:

```
In [46]: pattern.search('  0.  100.\n').groupdict()
Out[46]: {'raw_time': '', 'raw_value': '0.'}
```

I heavily rely on regex (sure, demo, but it was consistent with python till now).

Advice?

tnx

Comment: Please could you clearly show the input on which it's not working (like you do in the working example). Thanks.

Comment: Reggex buddy won't help you with Python regexes. You'll need a Python regex tester like: http://ksamuel.pythonanywhere.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.+` that you've added needs to be changed to `.*`.

The `+` operator requires *at least one character*, whereas `*` will accept zero or more.